# When is assembly language used?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction

I am taking a class in computer organization and I see this clip:

[image]

Why would the compiler writer need to know assembly language? Doesn't the compiler translate high level languages like Java to binary (or bytecode in the case of Java)? When does assembly language come in?

There is this quote from my book:

> high-level programming language A portable language such as C, C++, Java, or Visual Basic that is composed of words and algebraic notation that can be translated by a compiler into assembly language.

I really thought a compiler goes from high level language to binary. Is this not right?

Comment: The "binary" generated by compilers are the binary-encoded assembly instructions.

Comment: It makes more sense to compile to assembly language for a number of reasons than  straight to machine code.  Only some of the information generated by the compiler results in actual instructions.  The assembler comes before the compiler for a target, so there is always an assembler there.

Comment: the term toolchain comes from a chain of tools, compiler, assembler, linker

Comment: only part of an assembly language is the syntax related to instructions.  there is a fair amount that is not instructions, but is very valuable in being able to define labels that are then later linked using the linker, like "main" for example, or "printf".  why re-invent a wheel?   some folks will compile straight to machine code in the same way that some folks write operating systems in assembly language, because they can.  Like why did you climb the mountain?  Because it was there.

Comment: the list is missing the bootstrap needed for a compiled language.  For example what would your language choices be for bootstrapping C?

Comment: what is  imbedded processor programming?

Comment: Why does my question have like 8 responses and yet a -1? wtf is wrong with stackoverflow?

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly possible for a compiler to emit assembly in text form, which is then fed into an assembler, rather than emitting binary machine code directly (GCC does this for example), but I don't think the author of that slide even made that distinction. Assembly and machine language are basically different presentations of the same language, so the distinction isn't really that meaningful.

In fact I'd find it hard to believe that anyone knowing a given machine's machine code wouldn't also know its assembly language - almost certainly you'd learn the machine code by first learning the assembly form and then looking up the binary values in the machine's data sheets.

> or bytecode in the case of Java

To write a bytecode compiler, you don't need to know assembly or machine language. That's true. (You would need to know it to implement the JVM's JIT compiler though).

Comment: when you say machine language do you mean binary?

Comment: @Jwan622 In the context of file format, "binary" just means "not text". It's not the name of a specific file format. For example, PDF is a binary format (as well as most graphics, video or audio formats, etc.), but certainly a CPU can't execute PDFs. When I say machine language, I mean the specific binary format that a given CPU understands.

Comment: @Jwan622 It does mean that (though in the context of file formats it more specifically means "a sequence of 0s and 1s that doesn't represent plain text" because otherwise every file would be a binary file and the term "binary file" would be pointless). But not every sequence of 1s and 0s can be executed by a CPU.